# Fine uploader: hide total progress bar (and label) upon validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Upload (http://fineuploader.com/) and its corresponding [total progress bar](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/progress-bars.html).

This is my html:

```
<div id="totalProgress" class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

The total progress bar works fine when I'm uploading files and is hidden when the upload is finished.

But I am also using validation

```
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
        itemLimit: 5,
        sizeLimit: 5000000
    },
```

The problem is that the progress bar is stil visible after a validation fail. For example, I tested to upload 6 images (validation error) and the progress bar was still visible. This might be because the html div doesn't get the css class `qq-hide` after validation error:

```
.qq-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

I have tested to add it in my fineuploader function if the file is rejected but it's not working:

```
.on("REJECTED", function() {
        $('#totalProgress').addClass('qq-hide');
});
```

***Unexpected Scenario 1: validation pass***

1. The total progress is hidden before the upload with qq-hide.
2. I upload a file that passes the validation, qq-hide is removed
   (progress bar visible)
3. qq-hide is added again when the upload is finished (progress bar
   hidden again).

***Unexpected Scenario 2: validation fail***

1. The total progress is hidden before the upload with qq-hide.
2. I upload a file that **not** passes the validation (e.g. to large),
   qq-hide is removed (progress bar visible)
3. Get a validation error message
4. qq-hide is **not** added again after the validation error (progress
       bar still visible).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Please try to rephrase with a series of specific steps needed to reproduce the issue. I'm also not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Updated my question with 2 scenarios with total progress bar. Validation pass and validation fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following [**from the API**](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/progress-bars.html):

> In Fine Uploader UI, the total progress bar will be hidden once it reaches 100%, or once there are no longer any files in progress.

Therefore, if you define the total progress bar as follows (without other attributes):

```
<!-- Total progress bar -->
<div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Then it will automatically be made invisible if an upload fails (due to e.g. a validation error).

Note the following ([from the owner of Fine Uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1175#issuecomment-39114596)) about this behaviour:

> **There should be no content inside the qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector** other than the qq-total-progress-bar-selector element as the progress-bar element is intended to consume all of the space in the progress-bar-container.
>
> If you want to add other text that is dependent on the visibility of the total progress bar, you'd need to rethink your design a bit, and perhaps observe the totalProgress event to show/hide that label in the DOM.

So you could, for example, monitor the progress bar itself and then add a label if progress > 0%. This can be done by using the [**`progress events`**](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#totalProgress) This way your label is only added when the upload has passed the validation.

I've prepared a working jsFiddle for you with both a *total* progress bar and *individual* progress bars.
You can see that it works fine now, if nothing else is inside the `qq total progress bar div`:

### [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xqn2L60p/)

Comment: Note that Fine Uploader also provides [totalProgress and progress events](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html).

Comment: @RayNicholus: I was looking for those :) I will update the link.

Comment: @downvoter I know the links are broken, but is that really a reason to downvote? You could've also fixed the links yourself with an edit.